# Apache HttpClient PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager leaking connections?

Tags: scala, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, spray

I am using the Apache Http Client in a Scala application.

The application is fairly high throughput with high parallelism.

I am not sure but I think perhaps I am leaking connections.  It seems that whenever the section of code that uses the client gets busy, the application become unresponsive.  My suspicion is that I am leaking sockets or something which is then causing other aspects of the application to stop working.  It may also not be leaking connections so much as not closing them fast enough.

For more context, occasionally, certain actions lead to this code being executed hundreds of times a minute in parallel.  When this happens the Rest API (Spray) of the application becomes unresponsive. There are other areas of the application that operate in high parallelism as well and those never cause a problem with the applications responsiveness.

Cutting back on the parallelism of this section of code does seem to alleviate the problem but isn't a viable long term solution.

Am I forgetting to configure something, or configuring something incorrectly?

The code I am using is something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  val connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()
  connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50)
  connectionManager.setMaxTotal(500)
  val httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build()

  def postData() {
    val post = new HttpPost("http://SomeUrl") // Typically this URL is fixed.  It doesn't vary much if at all.
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity("Some Data"))
    try {
      val response = httpClient.execute(post)
      try {
        // Check the response
      } finally {
        response.close()
      }
    } finally {
      post.releaseConnection()
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I can see that I am building up a lot of connections in the TIME_WAIT state.  I have tried adjusting the DefaultMaxPerRoute and the MaxTotal to a variety of values with no noticeable effect.  It seems like I am missing something and as a result the connections are not being re-used, but I can't find any documentation that suggests what I am missing.  It is critical that these connections get re-used.

**EDIT 2**

With further investigation, using lsof -p, I can see that if I set the MaxPerRoute to 10, there are in fact 10 connections being listed as "ESTABLISHED".  I can see that the port numbers do not change.  This seems to imply to me that in fact it is re-using the connections.

What that doesn't explain is why I am still leaking connections in this code?  The reused connections and leaked connections (found with netstat -a) showing up in TIME_WAIT status share the same base url.  So they are definitely related.  Is it possible perhaps that I am re-using the connections but then somehow not properly closing the response?

**EDIT 3**

Located the source of the TIME_WAIT "leak".  It was in an unrelated section of code.  So it wasn't anything to do with the HttpClient.  However after fixing up that code, all the TIME_WAITs went away, but the application is still becoming unresponsive when hitting the HttpClient code many times.  Still investigating that portion.

Comment: To analyze why your spray app becomes unresponsive (if you think that this may be a problem) you may want to gather some stack traces to see where Akka/spray threads are spending their time with. Use `jps` and `jstack` on the console to do this. Feel free to post on the spray mailing list about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider re-using HttpClient instance or at least the connection pool that underpins it instead of creating them for each new request execution. If you wish to continue doing the latter, you should also close the client or shut down the connection pool before they go out of scope.

As far as the leak is concerned, it should be relatively easy to track by running your application with context logging for connection management turned out as described [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html)

Comment: The sample code above doesn't make it entirely clear, but the class above only gets created once.  As such the HttpClient and ConnectionManager are reused for every request.

Comment: I see. You still ought to shut down the connection pool whenever an instance of this class is dereferenced or is about to go out of scope. Besides, the bit about connection management context logging still stands. That should at least give you an idea if all connections get correctly released back to the pool

Answer (score 0):

IMO - you can use a much lower number of maxConnection per domain ( like 5 instead of 50 ) and still completely saturate your network bandwidth, if you use http efficiently.

im not a scala person ( android , java ) but have done lots and lots of optimization on http client side threadpools. IMO - blindly increasing connections per domain to 50 is masking some other serious issue with thruput.

2 points:

if you are using a shared "sharedPoolingClientConnManager" , correctly going to a small pool per domain and you conform to the recommended way of release your conn back to the pool ( you should be able to debug all this seeing a running metric of the state of connection per threadpool instance ) then u should be good.

whatever the parallelism feature of scala , you should understand something of how the 5 respective threads from the pool on a domain are sharing the socket??  IMO from the android/java experience is that even though each thread executor is supposedly doing blocking I/O to the server in the scope of that httpclient.exec statement, the actual channel management involved allows very high thruput without resorting to ASNyC client libs for http.

Android experience may not be relevant because client has only 4 threads. Having said that , even if you have 64 or more threads available , i just dont understand needing more than 10 connection per domain in order to keep your underlying http socket very , very busy with thruput.